# Locale.getDisplayLanguage(inLocale) does not give correct value for norwegian locale

Tags: locale

I have a java application where there is a dropdown to change the language of the application. The current Languages that we support are :
1. English
2.German
3. French
4. Czech
5. Japanese
6. Polish
7. Portuguese
8. Spanish
9. Dutch
10. Chinese.

When the language is changed then the Dropdown list is also to be shown in the new language.
To do this I am using Locale.getDisplayLanguage(inLocale).
It is working fine for the above mentioned languages.
Now I have to add a new language Norwegian.
**Sample code:**

```
    no = new Locale("no", "NO");

    System.out.println(Locale.CHINESE.getDisplayLanguage(no));
```

Here the output should be "Kinesisk" but the output that comes is "Chinese"

SO the getDisplayLanguage(inLocale) does not work for Norwegian Locale.
*Any help here??*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `no = new Locale("no", "NB");`. I think it's NB

http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

```
Type: language 
Subtag: nb
Description: Norwegian Bokmål
Added: 2005-10-16
Suppress-Script: Latn
Macrolanguage: no
```

EDIT: Also, I presume you must have data available in a dictionary somewhere. Else it's probably going to default to the English verison.